# I need an explanation of this code, the output is different from what I understand of the apply function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need, please, an explanation of this code:

```js
const array = ['a', 'b'];
const myElements = [0, 1, 2];
array.push.apply(array, myElements);
console.info(array);
```

If the "apply" functions calls the push function for each of the elements in myElements, then my expected output should be something like

```
["a", "b", 0, "a", "b", 1, "a", "b", 2]
```

Instead it's

```
["a", "b", 0, 1, 2]
```

Why?

Answer (score 5):

The call

```
array.push.apply(array, myElements);
```

is effectively the same as

```
array.push(0, 1, 2)
```

The `.apply()` method invokes the function with the array elements of the second parameter as the individual parameters in the function invocation. It's pretty much like using a spread:

```
array.push(... myElements);
```

Note that the `.push()` method is called **once**, not once for each element of the array (either of them).

Comment: Thank you for answering. In the definition of "func.apply(thisArg, [ argsArray])", it says the argsArray is an array-like object, specifying the arguments with which func should be called. I understand that it will call the function FOR EACH element of the argsArray. So I am confused still

Comment: @Rafael no. It calls the function **once**, with the contents of the array like argument used as the first parameter, the second parameter, the third parameter, and so on.

Comment: I now see it, it says that the function will be called on those elements, it doesn´t say for each. I got it. Thank you